# How to change a global variable value based on linq query while executing

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have two module-level variables and Linq query. I want the results of the Let clause to change the global variables - is this possible?

For example:

```
Dim X As Integer = 0
Dim Y As Integer = 0
Sub One()
    Dim query = From e In <picture> _
                    Let X = e.@x _
                    Let Y = e.@y _
                Select <image X=<%= X %> Y=<%= Y %>><%= Two() %></image>
End Sub
Function Two()
    Return <X><%= X %></X>
End Function
```

What I need to do is assign X and Y in `Sub One`'s query and then have the query automatically use those updated values in `Function Two`. The `Let` clause does not allow me to do this as that only sets in-query variables. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass X and Y as arguments to the function Two() eg

```
Sub One()
    Dim query = From e In <picture> _
                    Let X = e.@x _
                    Let Y = e.@y _
                Select <image X=<%= X %> Y=<%= Y %>><%= Two(X,Y) %></image>
End Sub

Function Two(X as int, Y as int)
    Return <X><%= X %></X>
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Winston. It appears that this may be the only option as I have not been able to find another way. Thanks.